# Quickest way to iterate through a string, replacing a specific item if it exists?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm receiving strings of either sentences or paragraphs of text from the user. I need to check each string and see if a specific word exists. If it does then it needs to replace it with a specific word tied to the one that was found.

I thought maybe using an NSDictionary and having the **key** be the word to search for and the **object** being the word to replace with. The iterating through the dictionary. - I think its close but need a little guidance.

```
NSString *inputText = userInput;
NSString *finalOutput;

NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                     @"awesome", @"dumb", 
                     @"because", @"apple", nil];

[dic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    finalOutput = [inputText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:key withString:obj];        
}];
```

So basically search X string of text for X words, if you find one then replace it with specified word and stop.

awesome => dumb

because => apple

cat => dog

**"This is a string of text, and it is an *awesome* string of text.. because it is full of foo."**

would turn into

**"This is a string of text, and it is an *dumb* string of text.. because it is full of foo."**

It should stop once it finds the fist word.
Am I headed the wrong direction or is there a better way to accomplish this? Perhaps with NSScanner?

Comment: Should stop once it has replaced all occurrences of the first word, or once it has replaced the first occurrence of the first word? Also, dictionaries are not ordered so you aren't guaranteed a "first" word, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old but try this to enumerate through a string and replace words.

```
NSString *fullText =@"Some text that needs to have words replaced!"
NSDictionary *replacementDict = @{@"replaced" : @"stuff"}

__block NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithString:fullText];
__block BOOL replacementDone = YES;


while (replacementDone) {
    replacementDone = NO;
    newStr = [NSString stringWithString:newStr];
    NSRange wordRange = NSMakeRange(0, newStr.length);
    [newStr enumerateSubstringsInRange:wordRange
                               options: NSStringEnumerationByWords
                            usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange,    NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){
                                NSString *lowWord = [substring lowercaseString];
                                if ([replacementDict objectForKey:substring])
                                {
                                    *stop = YES;
                                    newStr = [newStr stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:substringRange withString:[replacementDict objectForKey:substring]];
                                    replacementDone = YES;
                                }

                            }];
}


return newStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this for replacement of first word (replacing string) found in string:

```
NSString *str3 = @"This is a string of text, and it is an awesome string of text.. because it is full of foo awesome";
NSLog(@"%@",str3);
NSString *outputString;
NSRange range = [str3 rangeOfString:@"awesome"]; //Find string
if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{ 

    outputString = [str3 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"dumb"];

 OR use this

    //string exists
    //copy upto found string in new string
    outputString = [str3 substringToIndex:range.location]; 
    //now add your replace string plus remaining string
    outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dumb%@",[str3 substringFromIndex:range.location+range.length]]];    

    NSLog(@"%@",outputString);
}
```

Comment: You could also use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` to replace the word.

Comment: @Martin R yes its also best way to use